# Why does the minimization trick still work for infinite dimensional inner product spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I am currently self-studying Linear algebra done right and have reached the part about the minimization problem

> $6.58 $Example Find a polynomial u with real coefficients and degree at most $5$ that approximates $\sin(x)$as well as possible on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ in
> the sense that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\operatorname{u}(x)-\sin(x)|^2dx$$
> is as small as possible. Compare this result to the Taylor series approximation.
> Solution Let $\mathbb C_{\mathbb R}[-\pi, \pi]$ denote the real inner product space of continuous real-valued functions on $[-\pi, \pi]$ with inner product
> $$ \langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(x)dx$$
> $6.59$ Let $v \in \mathbb C_{\mathbb R}[-\pi, \pi]$
> be the function defined by $v(x)=\sin(x)$ Let $U$ denote the subspace of $\mathbb C_{\mathbb R}[-\pi, \pi]$ consisting of the polynomials with real coefficients and degree at most $5$. Our problem can now be reformulated as follows:
> Find $u \in U$ such that $\Vert u-v \Vert$ is as small as possible.
> To compute the solution to our approximation problem, first apply the
> Gram–Schmidt Procedure (using the inner product given by $6.59$) to the basis $1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5$ of $U$, producing an orthonormal basis $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{4}, e_{5}$ of $U$. Then, again using the inner product given by 6.59, compute $P_{U}v$ using $6.55$(i) (with $m=6$). Doing this computation shows that $P_Uv$ is the function $u$ defined by
> $$6.60 \space\space\space\space\space\space u(x) = 0.987862x - 0.155271x^3 + 0.00564312x^5$$
> where the $\pi$’s that appear in the exact answer have been replaced with a good decimal approximation.

My question is, in the derivation of the orthogonal complement, Mr. Axler uses the fact that the inner product space V is finite dimensional. However, here $\mathbb C_{\mathbb R}[-\pi, \pi]$ is an infinite dimensional inner product space. Does this mean that the proof does not apply here?

Comment: What do you mean by "derivation of the orthogonal complement", and why do you think that's relevant here?

Comment: In order to work with an infinite-dimensional projection space, you need to restrict the polynomial coefficients such that all such polynomials are bounded with respect to the induced norm.  Because you are not restricting the coefficients when working with the standard polynomial basis (in the statement you only require coefficients to be real), you are forced to deal with a finite linear combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C_{\mathbb R}([-\pi, \pi])$ is indeed infinite-dimensional, but here all the action takes place in the finite-dimensional subspace spanned by $U$ and $v$.
So we might as well use that as our inner product space.  All results for finite-dimensional inner product spaces are then fair game.

Comment: The main tool used in the solution given in the book is Theorem 6.56, which requires that the subspace $U$ be finite-dimensional (as is the case here) but does not require $V$ to be finite-dimensional. If you look carefully, you will see that nothing used in the solution requires $V$ to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: @Sheldon Axler In the proof at 6.47 why can the vector space V be infinite dimensional sir? I thought the proof is that we can write $v \in V$ as a linear combination of the orthonormal basis of U and an extended orthonormal basis. This makes the inner product $\langle w, e_{j} \rangle$ where $j \in \{1,2,3,…,n\}$ equal to $0$ for $w \in U^{\bot}$. Could you please explain where I got wrong in my understanding sir?

Comment: @Monai The proof of 6.47 never assumes that $V$ is finite-dimensional. Instead, the hypothesis of 6.47 is that the subspace $U$ is finite-dimensional. The proof uses only an orthonormal basis of $U$ and does not extend it to an orthonormal basis of $V$.